# Error when trying to click 'Title, Description, and Logo' from the Site Settings (2013)

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, error, site-settings

I haven't run into this particular problem before, and it seems rather strange to me.

I'm trying to make some changes to a site.  So, I go to *Site Settings*, of course.  From there, under *Look and Feel*, I click *Title, Description, and Logo*.  Instead of seeing what I expect, however, I get an error page that reads:

> "Sorry, something went wrong.  A list, survey, discussion board, or
>   document library with the specified title already exists in this Web
>   site.  Please choose another title."

This confuses me.  I'm trying to access the settings.  Any ideas on how to get around this?

Comment: Yes kind of unlogical but this worked for me too! https://johnmhester.wordpress.com/2014/01/31/error-changing-a-site-title-in-sharepoint-2013/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, It's strange behavior specifically when editing `lists Title, Description, and Logo` settings, where you can have multiple lists with the same display name without any issue in SharePoint but not recommended from user experience perspectives!

**So try to investigate the issue as the following:**

- Try to edit the list title using SharePoint Designer.

  - Open SharePoint Designer, Connect to the site.
  - Go to lists and library, Right click on your list, click list setting.

  [image]

  - Chane the list title by providing a new name >  Save > browse your list

  [image]

> **Note**: This doesn't change the list name, it just change the list title.

- Now, go back to edit the list title from the browser, and check if you still face the same issue or not.

**If the above solution didn't help, so try to do the following:**

- Make sure you didn't have a list with the same title name and try to change it or provide a new one for the current list, check [this](https://johnmhester.wordpress.com/2014/01/31/error-changing-a-site-title-in-sharepoint-2013/)  (Unlogic but may help)
- Also in this [article](http://support.kwizcom.com/KnowledgebaseArticle50110.aspx), it mentioned it may a permission issue.

Comment: Worth checking, of course.  However, it's a subsite name I'm trying to change, not a list or library name.  I'm guessing it's a permission issue, as I'm an SA, not an SCA.  I appreciate your help and guidance.

Comment: Welcome, @DanJ Yes, I know you need to just change the title, so I recommend to change it with your suitable name using SP designer and check it will be reflected or not! if reflected try now from GUI, also I mentioned one article takes about it may be related to permission issue, hope it help!